# Why two continuous tab and EOF in the script result in listing file in current directory?

Tags: bash, ls, heredoc

The normal and formal here doc in bash script is as below.

```
clear-mysql(){
    mysqlword="xxxxx"
    port="22"
    ip="11.22.33.44"
    tmpdb="xxxx"
    ssh -p $port   root@{$ip}  "mysql -u root -p$mysqlword <<EOF
        use ${tmpdb};
        UPDATE xx SET yy = replace(post_content, 'domain', '"http://$ip/wp"');
EOF"
}
```

And you can use another right format(a tab and `<<-` )in this kind of bash.

```
clear-mysql(){
    mysqlword="xxxxx"
    port="22"
    ip="11.22.33.44"
    tmpdb="xxxx"
    ssh -p $port   root@{$ip}  "mysql -u root -p$mysqlword <<-EOF
        use ${tmpdb};
        UPDATE xx SET yy = replace(post_content, 'domain', '"http://$ip/wp"');
        EOF"
}
```

Now i write a wrong format (two tabs and `<<-`) for this simple bash snippet as below.

```
clear-mysql(){
    mysqlword="xxxxx"
    port="22"
    ip="11.22.33.44"
    tmpdb="xxxx"
    ssh -p $port   root@{$ip}  "mysql -u root -p$mysqlword <<-EOF
        use ${tmpdb};
        UPDATE xx SET yy = replace(post_content, 'domain', '"http://$ip/wp"');
                EOF"
}
```

Copy and paste it into terminal.

[image]

I knew it is a wrong format and i knew the right here string format in bash.
What confused me is that why two tabs and `<<-EOF` and `EOF` result in listing all files in current directory?
Yes ,two tabs triggered auto completion,

```
[root@localhost tmp]# 
Display all 1137 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Tab and tab will display all 1137 ,instead of listing files in current directory.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be because the EOFs and tabs are within the double quotes? That is, they are now part of the string.

Comment: It seems your command is short enough to one-line it, or use backslash escapes instead.

Comment: In interactive shells, TAB is used for filename completion. Typing two TABs means to list all the possible completions.

Comment: The two tabs pasted might have triggered auto completion?